# Returns all values in 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data]
(
    [PorID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HourS] [int] NOT NULL
)        

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeData]
(       
    [HId] [bigint] NOT NULL,      
    [HName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [HHour] [int] NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].PortInfo
(
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PortName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

Even if the port is not present in the `Data` table it should return rows for all port in `PortInfo` table. Similarly, it should always return 24 records for each port. The result should display all ports for each record even if doesn't exist within the `Data` table.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking.  Are you trying to write a query that will join all 3 of those tables together, even if PortInfo doesn't have a linked record in Data?

Comment: Show your effort - what have you tried as a solution?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is result set of portid information for each hour for different ports,The port table will contain 1-8 port id's , hour table has 0-23 hours, Data table will have values for each port for each hour (0 to 23 hours), If port is not present in data table also it should add 24 records to the result set.eg: port 8 is not present it should return port id records i.e 8 records then for each 8 records 24 hours should be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Based on what you are telling me in the comments and me filling in some blanks, this is what I assume you are looking for. This will produce a record for every hour, for every port.

```
SELECT
    td.HHour,
    td.HName,
    pi.Id,
    pi.PortName,
    d.PorID,
    d.HourS
FROM
    dbo.TimeData td
FULL OUTER JOIN
    dbo.PortInfo pi
    ON  (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Data d
    ON  (d.PorID = pi.Id)
    AND (d.HourS = td.HHour)
```

Output:

[image]

> Some feedback to make this process easier. Share your schema (relationships) and/or some sample data. Also, consider creating more logical/intuitive names for your columns so that relationships and content may be implied.

**Original Answer**

This sounds like what you are looking for. The query below will return all port information (from `PortInfo`) even if its `Id` is not in the `Data` table (`PorId`). This is done by using a `LEFT JOIN` onto the `PortInfo` table.

```
SELECT
    po.Id,
    po.PortName,
    d.HourS
FROM
    dbo.PortInfo po
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Data d
    ON  (d.PorID = po.Id)
```

Now, you don't mention the how or if the 3rd table `TimeData` should be used, but if you wanted that information in your result as well, you can simply `LEFT JOIN` that as well:

```
SELECT
    po.Id,
    po.PortName,
    d.HourS,
    td.HName,
    td.HHour
FROM
    dbo.PortInfo po
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Data d
    ON  (d.PorID = po.Id)
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.TimeData td
    ON  (td.HId = d.HourS) -- I assume this is the link, you may need to update if not.
```

Comment: 8 Port-8 NULL NULL NULL

1 Port-1 14 14 2016-07-08 14:00:00.000

2 Port-2 14 14 2016-07-08 14:00:00.000

3 Port-3 14 14 2016-07-08 14:00:00.000

4 Port-4 14 14 2016-07-08 14:00:00.000

5 Port-5 14 14 2016-07-08 14:00:00.000

6 Port-6 14 14 2016-07-08 14:00:00.000

7 Port-7 14 14 2016-07-08 14:00:00.000 In the above result even thought there is no data available for port 8,It should display all 24 hours from hour table.24 records should be there for port 8.

Comment: I think you either need to better explain the relationships between all tables and/or provide some sample data

Comment: What I'm trying to do is result set of portid information for each hour for different ports,The port table will contain 1-8 port id's , hour table has 0-23 hours, Data table will have values for each port for each hour (0 to 23 hours), If port is not present in data table also it should add 24 records to the result set.eg: port 8 is not present it should return port id records i.e 8 records then for each 8 records 24 hours should be added.

Comment: The logic is like if a port is present in data table it should have all hours data (0 to 23), If a particular port is not present it should match with portinfo table and return all ports the select the 24 hours for each port.

Comment: I wish you would help better describe your schema and/or content of you tables. I don't have the luxury of knowing that and unless you provide it, I am limited in how I can help. Does `TimeData` have 24 records already in it??

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for Thank You.